# RDCL report viewer toolbar icons not visible Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, rdlc, report-viewer2012

**Code**

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer   ID="ReportViewer1"  Width="1140px" 
 ShowToolBar="true" Height="500px" runat="server">
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

I am geeting the following toolbar with no images of icons 
[Toolbar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZjZS.png)

I need the foolwing toolbar guys please have a look.
[desired toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70pfU.png)